# How to connect to MySQL database cluster

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench, dbeaver, mysql-cluster

I tried to install a MySQL cluster with the Docker image below.

[mysql/mysql-cluster - Docker Image | Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-cluster/)

The Docker image is pulled and run successfully.

Despite that I could connect to the cluster in the terminal (as shown in the screen capture below), I don't know how to connect to it with MySQL Workbench or DBeaver.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker run command, you can use `-p 3306:3306` (or any available port). Then you can use `<host>:<port>` from Workbench or Dbeaver connection URL.

Comment: As you replied, I deleted all the existing containers and created them again. The port below was specified during creation. `docker run -d --net=cluster --name=mysql1 --ip=192.168.0.10 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='tpffnrtm1!' -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-cluster mysqld` But in dbeaver I get an error as below. ▶ Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. connect timed out.

Comment: Are able to access your <host>:3305 through telnet/ nc ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already know how to add new DB connection to `MySQL Workbench` or `DBeaver`. The information that you want is **the connection URL** and **the username/password** of an authenticated user that you need to use to connect to your MySQL cluster.

**For the connection URL**: `192.168.0.10` (no port in your example)

You need to have your `MySQL Workbench` or `DBeaver` connect to the URL of **the MySQL node**, which is `mysql1` node in your example. As shown in your screen capture, it is `192.168.0.10` without any explicit port. But if you have troubles with the URL, you can run `docker ps` to check what host and port that your `mysql1` is running and exposed at.

**For the username/password**: root/tpffnrtm1 (the password is the value of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` as shown in your `docker run` of MySQL node command)

I assume that you just want to connect the DB cluster by any means (root or non-root privileges is totally fine for you).

Comment: As you replied, I deleted all the existing containers and created them again. The port below was specified during creation. `docker run -d --net=cluster --name=mysql1 --ip=192.168.0.10 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='tpffnrtm1!' -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-cluster mysqld`
But in dbeaver I get an error as below.
▶ Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. connect timed out.

Comment: Can you send me the info (connection string, driver, uname/password) that you used when trying to connect with dbeaver?